# VBA Conditional Format Zero value font colour white for Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. In each Worksheet, Columns C to T, I would like to format all cells containing zero values to white font color.

I tried the following script, but it only works in the current worksheet, not the whole workbook. Please could someone assist with a script that will work.

Appreciate the help!

```
Sub Macro1()

    Columns("E:T").Select

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=0"

    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just trying to hide the 0's? You can just use find & replace to replace 0's with nothing. Same effect (if your background is white) and you are indifferent to a cell being `0 with white font` or just `true blank`

Comment: If you want C to T then you'll have to look at your first line: `Columns("E:T").Select` should be `Columns("C:T").Select`

Comment: Sorry, that was a Typo. I want E:T. I cannot use find and replace because the data is in a pivot table. Also how do I allow the script to work for the whole workbook?

Comment: To operate on multiple `Workbooks` you would `Loop` through `Workbooks`. To operate on multiple `Worksheets` in a `Workbook` you need to loop through the `Worksheets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if the macro is run from the `Workbook` that you are running it on. If you would like to run it from one workbook on another make sure to change this line:

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

into

Set wb = Workbooks("**nameofyourworkbook**")

```
Option Explicit

Sub WhiteZeros()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'This will loop through the worksheets
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

    Set rng = ws.Columns("E:T")
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=0"

    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With rng.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    rng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Next

End Sub
```